# Как задать высоту UIButton в процентах от высоты экрана?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, constraints

Есть элемент UIButton отцентрованный constraints'ом по центру по вертикали, мне нужно чтобы высота этой кнопки ровнялась 50% высоты текущего экрана. Задать значение в точках выглядит сомнительно - экраны у телефонов разные. Не могу понять как реализовать такое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианта два:
1) если используешь Interface builder, то просто выставляешь constraint equal heigh с мультиплаером 1:2
2) если из кода, то получаешь высоту экрана UIDevice.main.bounds.height и делишь на два. Хотя более лаконичное решение это реализовать через высоту View и все с тем же мультиплаером

Comment: Спасибо, первый вариант - то что нужно)